# Scroll a UITextView like the Xcode debugger window

Tags: ios, scroll, uitextview

I have a UITextView that will have lines added as events happen, as a sort of log to show what is happening. I want it to function like the debugger window in Xcode. New line appears on the bottom and text automatically scrolls up as new text is added. I only need the text actually displayed to be stored, so purging text that leaves the textView would also be good.

In looking through the documentation, I see a method to scroll to the top, but not to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UIScrollView`'s `scrollRangeToVisible`:

```
CGPoint p = [helpText contentOffset]; 
[helpText setContentOffset:p animated:NO];
[scrollView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([scrollView.text length] - 1, 0)];
```

Comment: Thanks. That method worked differently from what I thought. I did have to add some additional code: CGPoint p = [helpText contentOffset];
            helpText.text = [helpText.text stringByAppendingString:text];
            [helpText setContentOffset:p animated:NO];
            [helpText scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([helpText.text length] - 1, 0)];

Comment: Yes, I was too quick with answering your question. I have added that to my answer.

Comment: Your first option worked. It just didn't scroll fast enough sometimes.